# Dynamically assign Result set

Tags: json, apache, apache-camel

Is there a way to dynamically assign a result set using Json? For example : I am using a VIEW for a select query to fetch some 250 odd columns from the database.I am using Apache Camel cxf with Spring DSL.I would have to assign all the columns got from the VIEW into a object using iterator. Please suggest a more simple solution.